# keras.fit and keras.fit_generator and train_on_batch difference results-help understand

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to understand why the results of training in three different training method in keras are different. I studied many answers so far, But I could not find answer.

The first two methods bellow show the same output/result.  Data are one-hot encoding of categorical data and some normalized numerical data.

First I train model using train_on_batch as follows:

```
# data set returns batch of data
pbar = tq.tqdm(enumerate(train_ds), total=len(train_ds)) ///// valid_ds for validation set
for i,d in pbar:
data1 = d[0]
 label1 = d[1]
 history = EC.train_on_batch(data1,label1) ///// evaluation EC.Evaluate(datat,labelt)
```

In other implementation I just use one line:

```
# data set returns batch of data
EC.fit_generator(generator=train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds,epochs=10)
```

In the last implementation I use another method in the code below. instead of getting a batch from dataloader, I get sample and collect them in a list as a batch. There is no difference in batch data and I don't shuffle the data. I mean order is same as order in the dataset. But here the result of training is different.

```
# data set returns one sample
pbar = tq.tqdm(enumerate(train_ds), total=len(train_ds))
for i,d in pbar:
    data1.append(d[0].copy())
    label1.append(d[1].copy())
    if (i+1)%batchsize==0:
        history = EC.fit(np.array(data1),np.array(label1),epochs=1,verbose=0)
        data1 = []
        label1=[]
```

I train models with small amount of data. When I train the model with the last method, I have no overfit. All three methods are doing the same job but data feed to the models is different. The two first method get batch from dataloader, the last method creates batch out of dataloader.

I appreciate for any help

Comment: It is probably due to random weight initialization, given the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that the two first model overfit but the last one does not overfit. I am using small amount of data for training.